# Android Error getting Bitmap from class

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

Getting a Bitmap from resources using the code below and then drawing it to canvas gives me no error.

```
mLetterA = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lettera), mScaledCardW, mScaledCardH, false);
```

But if I set the Bitmap in a class called Letter for example, then try get the Bitmap using the getter, say, getLetterGetBMP(), then I always get an error when I try to draw it on canvas. Why is that?

Comment: Show your stacktrace.

Comment: @user3396442 Post your code and Error Log